# How to draw multiple lines with different z index in c# wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, drawingcontext

I am using `DrawingContext.DrawLine` function to draw lines. But it seems like lines affecting the position of other lines on canvas. So I need to add different z-index values to all lines. Is there any way to draw lines with different z-index so they do not affect the position of other lines. Or is there any other method available to draw lines, like to draw text I have replaced `DrawText` method with `TextBlock`.

Below is the sample code I am using right now:

```
DrawingGroup dGroup = new DrawingGroup();
DrawingContext dc = dGroup.Open()
dc.DrawLine(penScaleMarker, new Point((float)newPointX, (float)newPointY), new Point((float)newMinorEndX, (float)newMinorEndY));
```

Comment: In a DrawingContext, the z-order is determined by the order in which you draw elements. It isn't clear why exactly you are using a DrawingContext at all. Why not add Line elements to a Canvas?

Comment: Actually the position and number of lines to draw are dynamic so is it possible to add line element to canvas ? If yes then please let me know how to do that.

Answer (score 5):

In order to add a dynamic collection of shapes to a Canvas, you would typically declare an ItemsControl with a Canvas as its `ItemsPanel`. The `ItemsSource` property of the Canvas would be bound to a collection of data items which represent shape data in an abstract manner. The `ItemTemplate` of the ItemsControl would be responsibe for visualizing each individual item.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ShapeItems}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Path Data="{Binding Geometry}"
                  Stroke="{Binding Stroke}"
                  StrokeThickness="2"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The view model that defines the data item class would look like shown below. Note that besides the `Geometry` and `Stroke` properties, you might have other properties that define the visual appearance.

```
public class ShapeItem
{
    public Geometry Geometry { get; set; }
    public Brush Stroke { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ShapeItem> ShapeItems { get; }
        = new ObservableCollection<ShapeItem>();
}
```

and you might instantiate and initialize it in your MainWindow like this:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var vm = new ViewModel();

    vm.ShapeItems.Add(new ShapeItem
    {
        Geometry = new LineGeometry(new Point(100, 100), new Point(200, 200)),
        Stroke = Brushes.Green
    });

    vm.ShapeItems.Add(new ShapeItem
    {
        Geometry = new LineGeometry(new Point(200, 200), new Point(100, 300)),
        Stroke = Brushes.Red
    });

    DataContext = vm;
}
```

---

You may now add a `ZIndex` property to the ShapeItem class

```
public class ShapeItem
{
    public Geometry Geometry { get; set; }
    public Brush Stroke { get; set; }
    public int ZIndex { get; set; }
}
```

and add the following to the ItemsControl:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ShapeItems}">
    ...
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="{Binding ZIndex}"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

---

The ShapeItem class would also have to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in case its properties change their values after having been added to the collection.