# ItemsControl binding error

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, itemscontrol

I have a Canvas inside an ItemsControl whose ItemsSource is an ObservableCollection. Withing this is a Rectangle whose Width property is bound to RectangleOverlay's wWdith property. Width appears 0 no matter what I have tried & I have tried moving things around. 
Here is the View.

```
<Grid>
        <Label  HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                Content="IMAGE FROM CAMERA" 
                Width="Auto" FontFamily="White"
                Canvas.Left="50" Panel.ZIndex="2"/>
        <ItemsControl Panel.ZIndex="3" 
                   ItemsSource="{Binding Source=MyProperty}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Canvas Height="Auto" >
                    <Rectangle Width="{Binding Path=wWidth,
                                       UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                           Height="50"
                           Canvas.Left="50"
                           Canvas.Top="50"                                   
                           Stroke="Red"
                           StrokeThickness="2"/>
                    <TextBox Canvas.Left="50"
                         Canvas.Top="100"
                         Text="TEXT"/>
                </Canvas>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>

</Grid>
```

And here is  the code for RectangleOverlay class

```
public class RectOverlay : Shape, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public RectOverlay()
    {

    }

   //I DONT KNOW WHAT EXACTLY NEEDS TO BE IN HERE 
    protected override Geometry DefiningGeometry
    {
        get { return new RectangleGeometry();}
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    private double _width;
    public double wWidth
    {
        get { return _width; }
        set
        {
            _width = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("wWidth");
        }
    }


}
```

And here is most of the code behind(MainWindow.xaml.cs).

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private ObservableCollection<RectOverlay> ListShapes;


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = this;

        MyProperty = new ObservableCollection<RectOverlay>();

        ListShapes.Add(new RectOverlay() { wWidth = 100 });

        _timer = new Timer(2000); // Set up the timer for 3 seconds
        _timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(_timer_Elapsed);
        _timer.Enabled = true; // Enable it
    }

    public ObservableCollection<RectOverlay> MyProperty
    {
        get { return ListShapes; }
        set
        {
            ListShapes = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MyProperty");
        }
    }


}
```

I cannot seem to understanding why the binding fails.

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'wWidth' property not found on 'object' ''Char' (HashCode=5046349)'. BindingExpression:Path=wWidth; DataItem='Char' (HashCode=5046349); target element is 'Rectangle' (Name=''); target property is 'Width' (type 'Double')
```

I have read & tried to figure out from other similar posts on SO about how to infer this error. I think I have the binding flow correctly set. The data context of the entire window is the code behind, there after ItemsControl Source is the ObservableCollection of a custom class(RectangleOverlay). & inside Data Template, I am setting path to a property of my Custom class.

Comment: I don't understand what all this is supposed to do. As a note, setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the Rectangle's Width Binding is entirely pointless. And why in the world is RectOverlay derived from Shape? Shape is a UI element, which does not belong to a view model, besides that you never actually show it anywhere.

Comment: ultimately have an ObservableCollection of Rectangle shapes(overlays) whose xpos & ypos will keep changing. Since default Shape class does not have x &  y, I have a custom Rectangle class where I will introduce X & Y. But for this example, just trying to implement collection with 1 Rectangle whose width is set to 100 & so hoping to see a Red rectangle of W=50 & H=50 at  listed X,Y positions(Canvas.Left & Canvas.Top)

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22325266/1136211) for how to show Rectangles in an ItemsControl using MVVM. It makes absolutely no sense to derive from Shape in a view model. What you may use is class Geometry and classes derived from it like RectangleGeometry.

Comment: As shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40720205/1136211

Answer (score 1):

The first error is that you wrote

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source=MyProperty}"
```

instead of

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyProperty}"
```

or just

```
ItemsSource="{Binding MyProperty}"
```

Setting the Bindings's Source object to `MyProperty` just assigns the string literal `"MyProperty"`, which is an IEnumerable of Chars and hence interpreted as such.

The Binding in the ItemTemplate then inevitably complains that it couldn't find a `wWidth` property on an object of type `Char`.

---

But there is another problem you are facing.  Here's the correct answer and to be honest I had to dig to get this for you... I've never had this problem before.

First, since you are using a custom shape the `ItemsControl` is ignoring the custom `DataTemplate` and attempting to draw the `RectOverlay` that you've provided.

Now of course you're not seeing this because you're setting only the `wWidth` of it, which isn't a real drawing width.  You need to set the `Width`, `Height`, `Stroke`, `StrokeThickness` etc to your custom shape and then you need to remove the `DataTemplate` completely from your `XAML`.

However, once you do that you'll still notice it doesn't draw.  This is because your `DefiningGeometry` is returning a blank `RectangleGeometry`.  This needs to be the paths etc that you intend to draw. (More on that if needed later.)

All that said, I truly don't feel that you need a custom shape here; if you do please give the full requirements and I'll provide a working custom shape and show have that working.  I did it on my machine here but I'm not going to post that code because I think it's not what you really need.

Another thing to note... If you are using a custom shape it is from type `DependencyObject`.  This means that implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` is overkill.  You can just use a custom `DependencyProperty` instead.

So please review this code below.  I modified the RectOverlay to be more of a ViewModel and I update the `MyProperty` in the `MainWindow` to be a `DependencyProperty`.

**Here's the `MainWindow` code behind**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        MyProperty.Add(new RectOverlay() { wWidth = 100 });
    }

    public ObservableCollection<RectOverlay> MyProperty
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<RectOverlay>)GetValue(MyPropertyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(MyProperty), typeof(ObservableCollection<RectOverlay>), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<RectOverlay>()));
}
```

**Here's the ViewModel `RectOverlay`**

```
public class RectOverlay : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private double wwidth;
    public double wWidth
    {
        get { return wwidth; }
        set
        {
            wwidth = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(wWidth));
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "") => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

I left the `XAML` the way you had it (except for removing Source=)

If you are sure you need a custom `Shape` then I can get that going also but also give me your use case for it so that I can get it right please.

Also, I removed the _timer because I wasn't using it to make the example.  Don't forget to add it back if you copy and paste.